# Cypress.io: Having own assertion-message?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, cypress

By default, the test-runner creates messages like those:

[image]

Based upon this code:

```
const parameterTableHeaders = ["Parameter ID", "Description", "Value", "Min", "Max", "Unit"];
cy.get("table[id*=parametersTable-header] tbody td bdi").each(($item, $i) => {
     cy.wrap($item).should("have.text", parameterTableHeaders[$i]);
});
```

It takes the ID of the checked DOM-element and combines it with the expected value. What I would like to have, would be something like e.g. "Expected first table-header to have text 'Parameter ID'." or "Expected table-headline to be ...".

Is that possible? Can one have own, **self-defined** messages?

Instead of the cryptic IDs, which the framework constructs.

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried for this?

Comment: @AlapanDas : Sure. Done!